# Re-use a React input props inside an hook: why the result isn't updated?

Tags: reactjs

In `ViewDispatcher` component I'm taking the input prop `initialItems` and creating the `items` variable using the `useList` hook from [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use) library. This help me to easly manipulate the list using i.e. the `update` method:

```
export const ViewDispatcher = ({ mode, loading, items: initialItems }) => {
  const [items, { update }] = useList(initialItems);
  console.log("[ViewDispatcher] Rendering", initialItems, items);

  switch (mode) {
    case "list":
      if (loading) {
        return null;
      }

      return <>{JSON.stringify(items)}</>;
    default:
      throw new Error("Unsupported view.");
  }
};
```

The problem I'm facing ([pen here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-currying-4ihpzw?file=/src/ViewDispatcher.js)) is: **why my `items` variable is empty, while the `initialItems` is populated correctly?** I disabled React strict mode for not polluting the log:

> [ViewDispatcher] Rendering [] []

> [ViewDispatcher] Rendering
> [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, …] []

The input `items` come from the `View` component which is just getting some data from

```
export const View = () => {
  const [{ loading, items }, setState] = useState({ loading: true, items: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((items) => {
        setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: false, items }));
      });
  }, []);

  return <ViewDispatcher mode="list" loading={loading} items={items} />;
};
```

Comment: You are initializing `items` with an empty array. Then when the prop changes the state doesn't update. This is basic. The initialization happens only once. To update the state you need to use the `update` method. Try some tutorials about react and state to get the hang of how it works. FYI you get the same exact behaviour with `useState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React saves the initial state once and ignores it on the next renders, and doing anything as such will be ignored:

#### 1. Update initial state via props ❌:

```
function ViewDispatcher(items) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(items);
}
```

On the first render, `ViewDispatcher` receives `[]` from items, and thus setting the initialState, on subsequent render caused by change of props, new values from `items` will be ignored.

#### 2. Recreating the initial state ❌:

```
function ViewDispatcher() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(createInitialStateFn());
}
```

On first render, state is initialized by `createInitialStateFn()` once, on subsequent renders, anything returned from `createInitialStateFn()` will be ignored.

#### To solve this

You can lift the `useList` up to the parent component and update the state using the `update` function from the `useList` library, just like `setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, loading: false, items }));` in the dot then block.

#### You might want to restructure state properly:

Both parent and child component keeps a hold of the `items` state, and there's a good chance that, you can merge these two state into one, otherwise, everytime state changes, you'll have to update both state using `setter` simultaneously, in order to keep them in sync.

And create a stand alone loading state specifically is best suited for your case I suppose:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot man. I figure it out. The only downside lifting up is that setLoading alone would trigger the rerender… but soon after setting the updated list would trigger again another render. That is why i keep the state in an object. Ideas? I’m kinda paranoid about rerenders maybe.

Comment: Rerendering isn't evil, unless you have up to thousands of items to render, which is a exceptionally rare case in UI, and premature optimization is in itself considered a bad practice, so, there isn't much point worried about performance/rerender, at the eairly stage of a project. Make it work first : )